# Receive return from external php

Tags: jquery, json

When I try to connect this from localhost it doesn't work. But I can see the JSON return from this url. How connect this from localhost? Can anybody help me?

```
$.post("http://slhub.com.lk/msg/country_list.php", function(html) {
    $("#countrylist").attr('disabled', true);
    var Data = { "Data": $.parseJSON(html) };
    $.each(Data.Data, function(i) {
        var id = Data.Data;
        $('#countrylist').append('<option value="' + id[i].country_code + '">' + id[i].country + ' (+' +  id[i].country_code + ')</option>');
    });
    $("#countrylist").attr('disabled', false);
});
```

Comment: You can't make an AJAX post to a different domain.

Comment: http://slhub.com.lk is your domain?

Comment: you can use CORS or POST MESSAGE or JSONP or their combinations. Check this keywords...

Comment: Agree with Igor, use JSONP.

Answer (score 0):

I added these headers to the php and it works fine. Thanks All.

`header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');`
`header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST');`
`header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');`